# How to integrate hubot with dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, hubot, discourse

I am trying to integrate hubot and dialogflow (api.ai) and can't find any solution.

I've tried https://github.com/ojacques/hubot-apiai and https://github.com/TMAers/hubot-dialogflow

but they both don't seem to work.  Any solutions out there?

Also, I have an adapter for discourse (discourse.org) but first I have to get hubot working by itself with dialogflow.

Comment: Hey Timothy, what isn't working exactly ? Is it the configurations ? the link between Hubot and DialogFlow ? We can't help without more details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, somehow I got it to work just now!  After about a week of working on solutions,  apparently both  https://github.com/ojacques/hubot-apiai and https://github.com/TMAers/hubot-dialogflow must be used together and a key must reside in the folder you have the hubot in, with your configurations pointing to that key.

There are a lot of steps in between, but if anyone is curious I can help.